# Red status bar showing when not recording and app in background

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, statusbar

I'm having a problem with the status bar on an app which does sound recording.  I've got

```
  <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
    <string>audio</string>
  </array>
```

in my plist in order to get the red status bar notification when sound is recording and the app is in the background.  However if I stop recording and go to background the status bar is still there.  I've seen this on an iPad 2 running 4.3.2 and an iPhone4 running 5.0.  I supect this is a > OS4 issue as I'm terminating the recording correctly and there appears to be no (certified) API to control the status bar.

Anyone seen this/know how to fix it?  I'm suspicious this could be an iOS bug but need to rule myself out first :)

The only thing I've seen on the web so far is this (unresolved) email thread:

http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/q7bub5A16vw9h9w2lw82

Andrew

Comment: I was the original poster on that thread.  The rest of the missing thread was that the issue went away for us with iOS 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

I do quite a bit of work with audio recording in background and have not seen this.  I have seen it "take a while" to go away, like seconds, but not get stuck with the red.

The PLIST entry that I use is different.  It is

```
Required background modes / App plays audio
```